# How do I check the system volume?

Tags: c#, winforms, volume

How can I check and change the system volume in Windows using C#, like so:

```
if(SystemVolume.vol == 0){
    SystemVolume.vol = 100;
}
```

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the concept of "audio sessions" in windows. There are some interfaces suggested by the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), namely `ISimpleAudioVolume`, `IChannelAudioVolume`, and `IAudioStreamVolume` interfaces.

The code examples given are in C++ though, but it should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 I created a package called [AudioControl](https://github.com/devmartins/AudioControl).

```
//Returns a float containing the value (ranging from 0 to 1.0f)
var volume = AudioControl.GetMasterVolume();

//Set the volume (use values between 0 and 1.0f)
AudioControl.SetMasterVolume(1.0f);
```